# prove almost sure convergence dws/(1-s) w is a brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Given the function $Y(t) = a(1-t) + bt + (1-t)\int_{[0,t]}\frac{dW_s}{1-s}$ with $t \in [0,1)$ we are asked to show the limit as $t \to 1$ of $Y(t) = b$.  $W_t$ is a brownian motion with distribution N(0,t).

The first 2 terms of $Y(t)$ are trivial but the last stochastic piece I am having some trouble proving.  The result would be sufficient if I can show the limit $t \to 1$ of term $(1-t)\int_{[0,t]}\frac{dW_s}{1-s}$ goes to 0 a.s., but I am not clear how to show this.

Comment: Does that not just reduce to the expectation of the square of that term evaluating to $-(1-t)^2\ln(1-t)$ with limit $0$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann at cursory first sight, I think OP is just supposed to use Ito's product rule on $\frac{W_s}{1-s}$ and then argue the limit